# table with scope excluded from felloe recursion members

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a scalar function which is recursive (calls itself in some cases). Is there any type of table that can ensure each instance of the function run in the recursion tree will not affect the rest?

I've read that #tables have session scope, and @tables have batch scope, however all of the instances are in both the same session and batch...right?

Here's a simple example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Factorial ( @iNumber int )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
-- I want to declare a table here which is independent for each recursion stage
DECLARE @i  int

    IF @iNumber <= 1
        SET @i = 1
    ELSE
        SET @i = @iNumber * dbo.Factorial( @iNumber - 1 )
RETURN (@i)
END
```

Comment: Are you searching for cycle detection? Please post your code, in current form this question is vague.

Comment: no...............

Comment: OK, I added an example

Comment: If you declare a table variable in the function body, the variable is private to that function instance and not shared with other concurrent invocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use table variable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Factorial ( @iNumber int )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @i  int;
  DECLARE @tab AS TABLE(i INT);  -- here

    IF @iNumber <= 1
      SET @i = 1
    ELSE
        SET @i = @iNumber * dbo.Factorial( @iNumber - 1 )
RETURN (@i)
END
```

Comment: What's the purpose from declaring `@tab` since you don't use it?

Comment: @Sami It is an example. Op does not state what he wants to achieve.